# add a class to an element after being clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a class to an element after an event listener detects a click of said element, I've used the following code, but it's not specific and any element being clicked will receive the class.

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   event.target.classList.add("selected");
});
```

what I thought would work was this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("object1");
document.element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   element.classList.add("selected");
});
```

Is there anything else I can use?

Comment: It's not `document.element.addEventListener` but `element.addEventListener`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Post that as the answer, I think this is what the OP is looking for

Comment: @Nitheesh I know but it seems to me that this question is a duplicate of hundreds of other questions :)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Please mark this question as a duplicate then

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
var element = document.getElementById("object1");
element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   element.classList.add("selected");
});
```

Comment: Please try to explain **why** this will work as part of the answer, code only answers generally encourage copy-pasting rather than actually learning what went wrong.